# I am getting C++ syntax error

Tags: c++, syntax-error

This script is supposed to read chars from keyboard, store them into arrays, and then output them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void storeArraysintoStruct(char[], int);

int main()
{
    char test[] ="";
    int a = 0;
    storeArraysintoStruct(test, a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void storeArraysintoStruct(char test[], int a)
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of entries: " << endl;

    cin >> n;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0, i<n, i++)

    {
        cout << "Enter your character: " << endl;
        cin.getline(test, n);
    }

    while (i < n)
    {
        cout << test[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }

}
```

Edit: fixed it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void storeArraysintoStruct(char[], int);

int main()
{
    char test[40] = "";
    int a = 0; 
    storeArraysintoStruct(test, a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void storeArraysintoStruct(char test[], int a)
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of entries: " << endl;

    cin >> n;
    int i;


    for (i=0; i < n; i++)

    {
        cout << "Enter your character: " << endl;
        cin >> test[i];
        if (test[n-1])
        {
        cout << endl;
        }
    }

     i =0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        cout << test[i] << endl;
        i++;
        if(test[n-1])
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

}

However, I am getting the errors Expected: primary expression before ")" and ";" before while. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The script doesn't work as expected, for it doesn't output the stored characters. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a simple case of knowing what the correct syntax for a language construct is (which should've been covered by the first tutorial you ever read on loops). Your `for()` should be `for(i=0; i<n; i++)` with `;` instead of `,`

Comment: thanks but no point in downvoting....

Comment: user3088723 this is a syntax error not a punctuation error. I have changed the title of the question

Comment: I didn't, so don't make assumptions

Comment: ALso, the script doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You need to reset `i` to zero after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error has already been pointed out in the comments. Also, as it has been mentioned, you never reset `i` after `for` loop, which prevents your `while` loop from running.

However, you have to also take in mind that this

```
char test[] = "";
```

allocates array `test` of only 1 character long. You cannot put more than one character of data into that array. In other words, your `storeArraysintoStruct` is sure to overrun the array and fall into undefined behavior territory.

In you want to preallocate a larger buffer for future use in `storeArraysintoStruct`, you have to specify the size explicitly. For example

```
char test[1000] = "";
```

will make `test` an array of 1000 characters. Of course, regardless of how large the array is, it is your responsibility to observe the size limit.

P.S. What is the point of that parameter `a`, if you never use it inside `storeArraysintoStruct`?

Comment: sorry, I was taught to use a as a limit of array parameter. But i forgot to use it.

Comment: @user3088723: Exactly. If you declared an array of size, say, `1000` in `main`, you should have passed that `1000` into the function through that `a` parameter. And then, inside the function, you should have used that parameter to make sure you don't overrun the buffer. Nothing like that is currently present in the code.